# AutoHotkey - How to click a control whose ClassNN changes?

Tags: winforms, autohotkey

I am trying to automate a workflow in a program and have hit a roadblock. I typically click buttons using `ControlClick`,  but for this particular control the `ClassNN` changes every time the program reloads. I tried using the control text, but there are two controls in the window that have the same text and it seems to prevent the command from executing.

Is there something else I can try to get `ControlClick` to work? Or is there another approach I can take? I don't want to click at (x,y) coordinates because the control may move depending on the user's resolution and task pane size.

The command I am using is:

`ControlClick, checkButton3, Bystronic BySoft 7`

This works for other adjacent buttons because they have unique control text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WinGet, List, ControlList, Bystronic BySoft 7
Loop, Parse, List, `n
{
    If InStr(A_LoopField, "WindowsForms10.Window") ; use only the part of the name that is always shown in WS
    {
        ControlGetText, Text, %A_LoopField%, Bystronic BySoft 7
        If InStr(Text, "checkButton3")
        {
            ControlGetPos, XX, YY, WW, HH, %A_LoopField%, Bystronic BySoft 7
            If (XX < ... && YY... &&...) ; relative position, you don't have to define it exactly)
            {
                ControlClick, %A_LoopField%, Bystronic BySoft 7
                    break
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If the controls are always checked in the same order, you can try this:

```
Index := ""
WinGet, List, ControlList, Bystronic BySoft 7
Loop, Parse, List, `n
{
    If InStr(A_LoopField, "WindowsForms10.Window") ; use only the part of the name that is always shown in WS
    {
        ControlGetText, Text, %A_LoopField%, Bystronic BySoft 7
        If (Text = "checkButton3")
        {
            Index++
            If (Index = 2) ; try also "If (Index = 3)" and "If (Index = 4)" until  you find the right one. If "If (Index = 1)" is the right one you don't need the variable Index.
            {
                ControlClick, %A_LoopField%, Bystronic BySoft 7
                    break
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than blindly clicking an (x,y) position. However, there are four controls with the same Text that are all relatively close to each other. The user can hide the ribbon, relocate the pane, etc, all of which will significantly adjust the location of the desired control. Unfortunately it seems like the position checking makes this solution somewhat unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same sort of problem in one app. Two buttons exchange ClassNN.

Call them buttons %Up% and %Down%. They are Button7 or Button9 and can be either WindowsForms 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 1234 or WindowsForms 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 1235.

I should note the two buttons are always one of the above two values. All the rest of the controls in the app remain constant. Once the app is running the %Up% and %Down% buttons do not change.

At the start of the app I look for the positions of the two buttons with a ControlGetPos for WindowsForms 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 1234 and another ControlGetPos for WindowsForms 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 1235.

The %Up% button is above the %Down% button on screen so the ControlGetPos with the higher screen position become %Up% and the other becomes %Down%

ControlClick, %Up%, Wintitle. %Up% being the WindowsForms 10.xxx.yyy.zzz 123? of the higher screen position

Regardless of screen resolutions the buttons position in relation to others determines what it will be labeled.